# Can snowpipe pick up files from within sub-folders?

Tags: amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowpipe

I'm looking to try to pick up all parquet files from an s3 bucket that have been placed into partitioned sub-folders by date.

In the past I've used snowpipe with a sort of 1-1 relationship, one sub-folder to one table; but I would be interested to know if it is possible to crawl over partitioned data to a single table.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Yes!

With COPY INTO you can load a particular file, a whole folder or all sub-folders within a certain folder. All you need to do is to adjust your path accordingly. Just mention the path in the FROM clause and all subfolders will be copied.

```
copy into mytable
from @my_stage/your_main_folder/;
```

Docs: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html

Edit: There are variations possible. Also the stage itself can point to a certain main folder already and you do not need to extend the COPY INTO path.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use sub folders as part of Snowflake Stage which you want to crawl in the Pipe Definition.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-auto-s3.html#step-3-create-a-pipe-with-auto-ingest-enabled

Make sure that the S3 Stage has the Sub folder path which you want to crawl.